# Can not read glove.6B.300d.txt in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, glove

I am trying to read glove.6B.300d.txt file into a Pandas dataframe.  (The file can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe)

Here are the exceptions I am getting:

```
glove = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ' ')
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 8

glove = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ' ', engine = 'python')
ParserError: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that read the glove file into a dictionary. It's more convenient and efficient to use this pretrained embedding.

```
embeddings_index = {}
f = open(os.path.join(filename), encoding='utf8')
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()
```

If your task need the dataframe version, you can convert it into dataframe by iterate the key, val in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

sample code for loading glove Embeddings as dict.

```
def load_glove_index():
    EMBEDDING_FILE = '../input/embeddings/glove.840B.300d/glove.840B.300d.txt'
    def get_coefs(word,*arr): return word, np.asarray(arr, dtype='float32')[:300]
    embeddings_index = dict(get_coefs(*o.split(" ")) for o in open(EMBEDDING_FILE))
    return embeddings_index

glove_embedding_index = load_glove_index()
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better to download and unzip from here:
https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove

After extracting you will get your glove file from the above link.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer. After you have gained a certain amount of reputation points, you will be able to post comments to other questions/answers.